# I have an issue with AudioGraph in Universal Window Platform

Tags: windows-10-universal

I have implemented an application that used AudioGraph in Universal Window Platform. My application need to create 2 instances of AudioGraph Object.First instance AudioGraph work as well but second instance AudioGraph will play audio faster. I expect both of instance object should play audio normally.

Who know the root cause of issue above please let me know. Thanks so much for your advices.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Source code  get a lot and complexity so I can't share here. But I can tell you I use this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/audiocreation/ to do my project.

After you download the project above. Please open Scenario1_FilePlayback.xaml.cs and go to function CreateAudioGraph. At there, you can see they use AudioGraph to play audio. My issue is: If I created second instance of AudioGraph object and play audio so second instance will play the audio faster (first instance of AudioGraph still be ok)